# Questions from private betas appear in real-time questions list

Tags: support, bug, stackexchange.com, question-lists

[image: real-time questions list with question from private beta]

That's a picture of my *real-time* list of questions on the main Stack Exchange site. The marked question is from the Politics.SE **private** beta. Should it really be shown there if no one except for committers of the Politics proposal can currently access it?